# Bash Execute command from other user with own variables

Tags: linux, bash

Hello I have a problem in Bash scripting with executing command from other user, when trying to call there my own variables.
It doesn't work:
`PATH='/home/test'
sudo -u test -s /bin/bash -c 'rsync -az $PATH/ test@server1.example.com:$PATH'`

It works only when I change the `$PATH to /home/test` which is not suitable. If will use another variable instead of PATH the result still the same. Problem that I do not know how to variables, when calling remote command. Is there any way to execute this command?

Comment: 1) Don't you the variable name `PATH`, it has a special meaning. 2) In the `sudo` command, use double quotes (i.e. `"..."`) so that variables get expanded.

Comment: Why not just `sudo -u test rsync -az "$path" "test@server1.example.com:$path"`? You don't need another call to `bash` here.

Comment: I used another variable instead of PATH and nothing has been changed.

Comment: It also does not work with double quotes.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good diagnostic.  `path=/moo/foo/bar; sudo "echo $path"` has the shell interpolate `path` inside the `sudo` command before running it.  `export path; sudo 'echo $path'` will work if `sudo` is allowed to import the exported variable.  See the duplicate question for details.